# Dependency injection fails for .Net Core 2.1 customized IdentityUI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

The new .Net Core 2.1 Identity is very confusing.

Here is my code:

STARTUP.CS

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options => options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>() 
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

DBCONTEXT

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
>   has been registered.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You registered `User` with Identity Framework, but somewhere in your project you have a class dependent on `UserManager<IdentityUser>`

Comment: @Nkosi So I should change this User : IdentityUser or IdentityDbContext?

Comment: No. Find out where you have `UserManager<IdentityUser>` and update that to `UserManager<User>`.

Answer (score 0):

`User` has been registered with Identity Framework as the extended user identity model.

However, the exception message implies that somewhere in the project has a class dependent on `UserManager<IdentityUser>`, which would have been the default from the template.

Since the default has been extended, then where ever there is reference to the default `UserManager<IdentityUser>` would need to be updated to `UserManager<User>`